# Clean filters and dusty house

Tags: hvac

I have good airflow and a very dusty house and large dust balls. I have used all kinds of filters including the pleated. When filters are checked in 3-6 months they are as clean as the day they were installed. I have filtered the vent in the bedroom to see if there was a hole in the duct, no dirt on the filter. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is on a forced air central heat-A/C, right? Are you getting good airflow?

Comment: Many filters need to be replaced every 30 days. If your return is in the wall or ceiling that may not be the cause of the dust bunnies